# Is it possible to upgrade my site from PHP 5.3.1 (XAMPP 1.7.3) to PHP 5.5.3 (XAMP 1.8.3)?

Tags: php, upgrade

please do not criticize me, I'm downloading the new xampp to try, but it would be nice to know now whether it is really possible.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.5? **YES.** Will it work _without issues_ in your specific scenario? **We can't answer that since you didn't provide any information.** Take a look at "Migrating from..." section of [PHP Appendices](http://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php). Backwards-incompatible and deprecated features are listed there.

Comment: thanks for answering... But calm down brow... I just asked if that is possible... And sorry about the wrong section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to upgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.5. However, you did not say anything about your code so it is unknown on whether the update will conflict with your code. Please be more specific next time.

Comment: thanks for answering, I was just afraid that I couldn't update it. but thx.